# Let $(x_n)$ be a convergent sequence with $\lim(x_n)=x>0$. Prove there exists a $K$ in $\mathbb{N}$ such that $x/2<x_n<2x$ for all $n\geq K$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I know that $x_n$ is a convergent sequence that converges to the limit $x>0$. The convergence hypothesis implies 
$$
|x_n-L|<\epsilon,
$$ 
which in this case means 
$$
|x_n-x|<\epsilon
$$ 
That gives us 2 inequalities which respectively are 
$$
\begin{align}
x_n&<\epsilon+x\\
&\text{and} \\
x_n&>x-\epsilon
\end{align}
$$ In the first case, if I let $\epsilon=x>0$ then, it gives me $x_n<2x$ and in the second case, if I let $\epsilon=x/2>0$, then $x_n>x/2$. Is that a correct proof and a good way to go about it?

Comment: For the left hand side, let $\varepsilon = x - x/2 = x/2 >0$ and apply the $\varepsilon \delta $ definition of convergence. For the right hand side a similar approach will work. Few people will answer this question, since you have not explained what you tried to solve it on your own.

Comment: I know, but I was really clueless as to where to start from. What you gave me really helped me! Am I on the right track now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The convergence hypothesis implies that

> for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $N$ such that, for $n\ge N$, $|x_n-x|<\varepsilon$.

You can choose whatever $\varepsilon$ you like. For instance, if we consider $\varepsilon=x/2$, we conclude that there is $N_1$ such that, for $n\ge N_1$, $|x_n-x|<x/2$, that becomes $-x/2<x_n-x<x/2$, in particular $x_n>x/2$.

If we choose $\varepsilon=x$, we find similarly $N_2$ such that, for $n\ge N_2$, $x_n<2x$.

Set $K=\max\{N_1,N_2\}$ and you're done.

In other words, your idea is correct but explained in a quite clumsy, if not incorrect, way